# How to get most recent categories - categories whose most recent posts published

Tags: categories

As the title, is there any way to get most recent categories, means that the categories whose most recent posts published?

Thanks!

Comment: The categories of the post most recently published? I'm just asking because it is a bit unclear.

Answer (score -1):

You will not be able to directly retrieve the categories of the most recent posts. You will have to query the posts first and parse out the categories.